# how to detect user is leaving the site in mvc3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

hi all this is my first question. I am beginner with web apps totally. and i using mvc3.
i am developing a site and wanna know when user leaves the site and then show him/her a message to confirm exiting. i also visited a good example for this propose in https://web.archive.org/web/20211028110528/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/demos/OnBeforeUnloadDemo1.htm but my question is: should i use this java script by writing it in all views or i can write it once and use it in every pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write in a master page.
That is:

- Master Page in regular ASPX based MVC site ([Sample](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/creating-page-layouts-with-view-master-pages-cs))
- _Layout.cshtml file in Razor based MVC site ([Blog Post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/30/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor.aspx)).

Comment: Thanks for the guy who voted down. And why was that? If it's wrong, comment.